# How Can I Open Multiple Files With xdg-open

Tags: wildcards, xdg-open, mpv

Let's say I run `xdg-open file.flac`. It will be equivalent to `mpv file.flac`. But if I run `xdg-open *.flac`, it will give me an error because it thinks that the other files are "unexpected arguments". What I want it to do is run `mpv *.flac`: a single `mpv`, with all the files matching `*.flac`, so they end up in a playlist.

Edit: I found a workaround for this:

```
printf "$sel" | sed -e "s/'/'\\\\''/g;s/\(.*\)/'\1'/" | xargs `printf "gtk-launch $(xdg-mime query default $(grep ${sel##*.}= /usr/share/applications/mimeinfo.cache | cut -d '/' -f 1)/${sel##*.})"`
```

`$sel` is the file(s) I want to open.

Comment: https://superuser.com/q/1722998/432690

Answer (score 2):

`xdg-open` doesn’t handle multiple arguments, so the best you can do is loop over the files:

```
for file in ./*.flac; do xdg-open "$file"; done
```

It isn‘t possible to get `xdg-open` to run `mpv *.flac`.

You could try working out the command to use manually:

```
$ xdg-mime query filetype *.flac
audio/flac
$ xdg-mime query default audio/flac
```

This should point to `mpv`’s desktop file, albeit without a path. Figure out where it is (using `$XDG_DATA_DIRS` or `/usr/local/share:/usr/share` if it’s not defined — look in the `applications` sub-directory), and extract [the `Exec` entry](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/desktop-entry-spec-latest.html#exec-variables); the `%F` place-holder specifies where multiple files are supposed to be named, if the application supports that.

Comment: This opens each of the files individually instead of doing `mpv *.flac`. It needs to be in a playlist.

Comment: OK, that isn’t possible with `xdg-open`.